# GIS read state plane coordinates and display on a map

Tags: gis, esri

I am new to Geographic Information Systems. I would like to read a file (from Java or Ruby ) that is stored on my local machine. This file will contain State Plane Coordinates (x,y) pairs. I would like to display those coordinates on a Map from Esri (preferred) or Google or some other provider. I am running on a MAC 10.7.5. Is there a simple way to execute the map application so that it displays the points described in the text file of (x,y) pairs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wan to read from a plain text file *using" Java or Ruby, right? I am not familiar with Esri, but you could display markers on a Google Maps map using their API. It is documented at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Answer (score 0):

ESRI arcgis has python scripting add-in. You can easily read a text file by using that. Or you can try QGIS, an opensource desktop GIS software. QGIS has a python interface also.